# difference between a program and software?

Tags: programming-languages

I've looked online and i've read the definitions but i still do not understand the difference. Does software require more than the knowledge of a programming language to create or is it more powerful/can it do more? Any input that could help clear the distinction would be appreciated.

Comment: Your title asks for the difference between "*program*" and "*software*", yet your question talks about "*programming language*". What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the question? For me those terms are interchangeable, and any difference is a technicality.

Comment: close; too broad & opinion based IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) A "program" is a kind of "software".  "Software" is a somewhat broader concept than just "a program".

2) Here's a good definition of software:

- http://www.openprojects.org/software-definition.htm

3) You can find other definitions, and they may or may not agree precisely with this one.

But I like this part of the definition:

> Software is created with programming languages and related utilities

This implies that, depending on how broadly you define "software" and how specifically you define "programming languages", you should be able to "create software" without necessarily knowing a programming language or using a compiler.

Comment: ok thanks, but based on your definition in the link does that mean that software doesn't need an os to operate? also, does that mean that  if an os restricts general programs from doing something (i.e. restarting a computer) software could restart the computer anyway since it doesn't rely on the os?

Answer (score 2):

I might tend to disagree with the other answers here, even though they cite specific definitions which I would agree with in a colloquial sense.

To me, a program is more of an abstract concept.  I can write out a simple program on a paper napkin if I wish (even in a made up language!), and it's still a program; though for sure it's not yet software.  A program is not necessary coupled to a particular mechanism in which it's stored.  For example, a program can exist within the firmware of a computer chip.

Software, to me, specifies a mutability.  As opposed to hardware, software can be changed through the functionality inherit to the device.  I can install new software, I can compile it or copy it.  It exists apart from the intrinsic abilities of the device itself.

I would say I can use software as a mechanism to convey the instructions defined by a program to a computer.  In other words, software can hold the definition of one (or more than one) programs, in the context of a specific set of hardware.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, the terms are interchangeable.

*A computer program (also software, or just a program) is a sequence of instructions written to perform a specified task with a computer.[1]*

Answer (score 1):

To me, a program is a special piece of software that can be started, executed, and which runs eventually to completion.

However, a piece of software might be a patch, a plugin, etc. You don't call these "programs" because they can not be executed as is.

The term software, or piece of software, is used in both cases to refer to the kind of "material" they are made of, namely, code.

Answer (score 1):

I like it even broader:

**Software** is everything you can transport over a wire (such as via telephone).
Everything else is **Hardware**.
Hence, money (or better, the claim of ownership of some sum of money) is software, while a bowl of spaghetti is hardware.

A computer program is a specific form of software used to program computers.

Answer (score 1):

A **program** is an instance of an algorithm written in some programming language such java, C++ but **software** is a collection of individual programs well packaged to run on a computer

Comment: You could write a program in *several* programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

**Program:** A program is a set of instructions(commands) written in computer language to provide solution for a particular problem using computing devices is commonly referred as Program.

**Software:** A Software is a solution of collections of domain of problems which is responsible for manual to automated.
A Software automate delivery of functions of a system using computing devices and ICT infrastructure.Software include following components:

1. SRS document.
2. Software design document.
3. Software line of code(LOC)
4. Software Testing document.
5. Software implementation document.
6. Software maintenance document.

Answer (score 0):

The software is something that a machine can execute. It's something with instructions that an operating system can understand.

A programming language is a language in the "middle" of a user and a machine that can easily be converted (by a machine) to a code that the machine can directly understand (software).

A programming language declares the syntax of a parser that translates the language to the machine code (translates to software).

Answer (score 0):

Yes software in a much broader sense refers to the set of computer procedures that describe programs and how they are to be executed while programs are a sequence of instruction given to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

**Program:** A program is a  sequence of instructions to solve a purticular problem or to perform a specified task with the computer. A program is written by using programming languages like Java, C++ etc. And they are compiled to machine code  understandable for the computer.

**Software:** A software is collection of individual programs well packaged to run a computer. A software is something that the machine can execute. It is something with instructions an operating system can understand. Software is made up of programming languages and related utilities.

Answer (score 0):

In a common sense, software usually means to a complete set. A software may consist of various components such as graphics, video and several other formats of data.

Programming language refers to communicate instructions to a machine such as C++, Python. A software language may also refer to a human interface language such as English, Japanese etc.

There is also difference in terms of duties. Software engineering is essentially a team activity. A software engineer may communicate with customers and develop solutions that fulfills their needs. Programming is primarily a personal activity and a programmer tends to work alone.

While looking from different aspects, there is a bigger difference between "software" and "program".